# Write file to user chosen path in external memory card android

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I am currently doing an app to store a text file into user chosen path in internal or external. My problem is that when I am trying to write file in internal storage, it perfectly work. I want to write the file to external memory card when user chooses a path inside the memory card.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
                        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose directory"), 9999);
                    }
```

And In onActivityResult

```
 Uri treeUri = data.getData();
   String path = FileUtil.getFullPathFromTreeUri(treeUri,this);
File dir =new File(path);

                   
                    if (!dir.exists()) {
                        if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                            Log.e("ALERT", "could not create the directories");
                        }
                    }

                    file=new File(dir,fileName);

                    if (!file.exists()) {

                        file.createNewFile();
                    }
```

FileUtils class

```
public class FileUtil {

    private static final String PRIMARY_VOLUME_NAME = "primary";

    @Nullable
    public static String getFullPathFromTreeUri(@Nullable final Uri treeUri, Context con) {
        if (treeUri == null) return null;
        String volumePath = getVolumePath(getVolumeIdFromTreeUri(treeUri),con);
        if (volumePath == null) return File.separator;
        if (volumePath.endsWith(File.separator))
            volumePath = volumePath.substring(0, volumePath.length() - 1);

        String documentPath = getDocumentPathFromTreeUri(treeUri);
        if (documentPath.endsWith(File.separator))
            documentPath = documentPath.substring(0, documentPath.length() - 1);

        if (documentPath.length() > 0) {
            if (documentPath.startsWith(File.separator))
                return volumePath + documentPath;
            else
                return volumePath + File.separator + documentPath;
        }
        else return volumePath;
    }


    private static String getVolumePath(final String volumeId, Context context) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            return null;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
            return getVolumePathForAndroid11AndAbove(volumeId, context);
        else
            return getVolumePathBeforeAndroid11(volumeId, context);
    }


    private static String getVolumePathBeforeAndroid11(final String volumeId, Context context){
        try {
            StorageManager mStorageManager = (StorageManager) context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
            Class<?> storageVolumeClazz = Class.forName("android.os.storage.StorageVolume");
            Method getVolumeList = mStorageManager.getClass().getMethod("getVolumeList");
            Method getUuid = storageVolumeClazz.getMethod("getUuid");
            Method getPath = storageVolumeClazz.getMethod("getPath");
            Method isPrimary = storageVolumeClazz.getMethod("isPrimary");
            Object result = getVolumeList.invoke(mStorageManager);

            final int length = Array.getLength(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                Object storageVolumeElement = Array.get(result, i);
                String uuid = (String) getUuid.invoke(storageVolumeElement);
                Boolean primary = (Boolean) isPrimary.invoke(storageVolumeElement);

                if (primary && PRIMARY_VOLUME_NAME.equals(volumeId))    // primary volume?
                    return (String) getPath.invoke(storageVolumeElement);

                if (uuid != null && uuid.equals(volumeId))    // other volumes?
                    return (String) getPath.invoke(storageVolumeElement);
            }
            // not found.
            return null;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
    private static String getVolumePathForAndroid11AndAbove(final String volumeId, Context context) {
        try {
            StorageManager mStorageManager = (StorageManager) context.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
            List<StorageVolume> storageVolumes = mStorageManager.getStorageVolumes();
            for (StorageVolume storageVolume : storageVolumes) {
                // primary volume?
                if (storageVolume.isPrimary() && PRIMARY_VOLUME_NAME.equals(volumeId))
                    return storageVolume.getDirectory().getPath();

                // other volumes?
                String uuid = storageVolume.getUuid();
                if (uuid != null && uuid.equals(volumeId))
                    return storageVolume.getDirectory().getPath();

            }
            // not found.
            return null;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private static String getVolumeIdFromTreeUri(final Uri treeUri) {
        final String docId = DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(treeUri);
        final String[] split = docId.split(":");
        if (split.length > 0) return split[0];
        else return null;
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private static String getDocumentPathFromTreeUri(final Uri treeUri) {
        final String docId = DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(treeUri);
        final String[] split = docId.split(":");
        if ((split.length >= 2) && (split[1] != null)) return split[1];
        else return File.separator;
    }
}
```

Comment: How did the user choose that path? Do you mean a path on a removable micro sd card?

Comment: User chooses the path using Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

Comment: Well that should go. Please post your code. And why did not you answer the other question? Any reason?

Comment: If the user chooses removable micro sd card then how can we write the file?

Comment: In onActivityResult you are not using the tree uri the user choosed. The code you posted has noting to do with the choice of the user or that action.

Comment: @blackapps can you share the code to convert tree uri to path?

Comment: You should not try to convert a tree uri to a path to begin with.

Comment: I got path using tree uri now its showing permission denied.

Comment: Repeat: `You should not try to convert a tree uri to a path to begin with. ` And you do. Dont! It is all pretty bad code.

Comment: Even if you manage to obtain a path for a file on a removable micro sdcard you will not have write access.  Such cards are not writable under Android since Android 4 Kitkat. Well not with classic file means. You should use SAF instead.